# silent failures when indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 6.4. We index about 100M documents with a node-js loader using the client 15.2.0.

The results are weird, because after every index we get different number of documents.

The code create a batch and after it reached a certain size it is loaded in elasticsearch with the bulk API. To be more performant we disable the refresh. If the bulk is rejected we wait 20 seconds and try again.

We checked also that response.error is true/false assuming that response.error = true means there are not failures.

Here the code:

```
if (i % options.batchSize === 0) {
            var previous_start = new Date();
            //sleep.msleep(options.slowdown);

            async.waterfall([
                function (callback) {
                    client.bulk(
                        {
                            refresh: "false", //we do refresh only at the end
                            //requestTimeout: 200000,
                            body: batch
                        },
                        function (err, resp) { 
                            if (err) { 
                                console.log(err.message);
                                throw err;
                            } else if (resp.errors) {
                                console.log('Bulk is rejected... let\'s medidate');
                                // let's just wait and re-send the bulk request with increased
                                // timeout to be on the safe side
                                console.log("Waiting for 20 seconds");
                                sleep.msleep(20000); // -> this is blocking... time for elasticsearch to do whatever it does
                                // and be in a better mood to accept this bulk
                                client.bulk(
                                    {
                                        refresh: "false",
                                        //requestTimeout: 200000,
                                        body: batch
                                    },
                                    function (err, resp) { 
                                        if (err) { 
                                            console.log(err.message);
                                            throw err;
                                        } else if (resp.errors) {
                                            console.log(resp);

                                            throw resp;
                                            // alternative would be to block again and resend

                                        }
                                        console.log("bulk is finally ingested...");
                                        let theEnd = new Date();
                                        return callback(null, theEnd);
                                    });
                            } else {
                                let theEnd = new Date();
                                return callback(null, theEnd);
                            }
                        });
                },
                function(end, callback) {
                    let total_time = (end - start) / 1000;
                    let intermediate_time = (end - previous_start) / 1000;

                    indexed += options.batchSize;
                    console.log('Loaded %s records in %d s (%d record/s)', indexed, total_time, options.batchSize / intermediate_time);
                    return callback(null, total_time);
                }
            ],
            function (err, total_time) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
            });

            batch = [];
            i = 0;
        }
    });
```

Looks like we have some silents failures. Anybody has the same issue? Any suggestion?

Moreover when looking at calling http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v, I get strange results on the column of the `docs.deleted`, what that column means?

```
health status index    uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   index_name Cqc2ABpRRs23P1DKlgaKJQ   5   0   96450728          340     24.8gb         24.8gb
```

sometimes this number changes during indexing, like:

```
 green  open   index_name WsJPPQLcTuuiw37Vv0lfhA   5   0   21958048         6594      6.6gb          6.6gb
```

(then this number decreases)

I could not find any explanation about it... any help on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a new index or you use an existing one each time?

For the deleted docs, you let es generate _id or you force it?

What is your batchSize ?

To index faster you also could turn offreplica during indexation (if you have one of course)
settings => NumberOfReplicas(0)
index_buffer_size could be upd too.

Comment: To answer your questions 
    1. we create a new index
    2. batch size is 1000
    3. refresh is disable as well as the number of replicas (set in the settings when creating the index)
    4. the _id is automatically generated